# How I can Histogram in Javascript with Array

Tags: javascript

Can I make one histogram in javascript with one Array, for example:

```
array = [1, 2, 2];
```

result:

```
1: *
2: **
```

I tried this:

```
array.reduce((acum,cur) => Object.assign(acum,{[cur]: (acum[cur] | 0)+1}),{});
```

my result:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Thank you

Comment: Ok. added my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) (and **not** a [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 2],
    result = array.reduce((acum, cur) => ({ ...acum, [cur]: (acum[cur] || 0) + 1 }), {});

console.log(result);
```

If you like to take `'*'` instead of the count, you could add stars.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 2],
    result = array.reduce((acum, cur) => ({ ...acum, [cur]: (acum[cur] || '') + '*' }), {});

console.log(result);
```